# Using Facebook request dialog with Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, meteor

I'm trying to send an "app" invite to user friends using the Facebook JavaScript SDK.
Here is a template event when click the Facebook button:

```
"click #fb": function (e, tmp) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
            requestPermissions: ['user_likes',
                'friends_about_me',
                'user_birthday',
                'email',
                'user_location',
                'user_work_history',
                'read_friendlists',
                'friends_groups',
                'user_groups']
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error when login with facebook " + err);
            } else {
                FB.api('/' + Meteor.user().services.facebook.id + '/friends', { fields: 'name,picture' }, function (response) {
                    if (response && response.data) {
                        friends = response.data;
                        friends_dep.changed();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

after that i want the user to invite people to my app, my code looks like this (another template event):

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'My Great Request'
        }, function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                    alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            }
        );
```

And it's working. There is a Facebook dialog with all the user friends, but when trying to send the message, I get the response error = 'Post was not published.'

What am I doing wrong here?

Basically the user can build a group - and I want the user to be able to invite his facebook friends into that group. Is there anyway that when sending the request the reciver will just press "yes" and will be automatically added to the sender group?

**note I'm using my local machine aka localhost:3000**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try removing the && response.post_id portion from the if statement?

According to the Facebook API docs for the Requests Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ the response will just have 'request' and 'to' data. It looks like you've copy and pasted your callback from an example they give for the Posts Dialog. If you still get an error after removing this then you aren't getting a response, I am unsure how the JS SDK handles responses. If you can get other API calls to work using js sdk then I'm really not sure.

I recently worked with the Facebook API and opted not to use the JS SDK because it seemed to be at odds with using the accounts-facebook package. I'm curious if you're using that too.

Some Facebook API calls like creating a Post (and possibly this one) do require a dialog box, I'll outline how I got around this without using the JS SDK in case it helps you or anyone else. I would just form the URL client side and open a popup window e.g. here's how I handled sending a post:

```
'click .send-message': function() {
  var recipient = this.facebook_id;

  var config = Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.findOne({service: 'facebook'});

  var url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + config.appId + 
  "&display=popup&to=" + recipient + "&redirect_uri=" + Meteor.absoluteUrl('_fb?close');

  window.open(url, "Create Post", "height=240,width=450,left=100,top=100");
}
```

Then to get the response server side:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers
.use(connect.query())
.use(function(req, res, next) {

  if(typeof(Fiber)=="undefined") Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');

  Fiber(function() {

    try {
      var barePath = req.url.substring(0, req.url.indexOf('?'));
      var splitPath = barePath.split('/');
      if (splitPath[1] !== '_fb') {
        return next();
      } 

     if (req.query.post_id) {
       //process it here
     } 

     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     var content = '<html><head><script>window.close()</script></head></html>';
     res.end(content, 'utf-8');

    } catch (err) {

    }
  }).run();
});
```

This code is very similar to the code used in the oauth packages when opening the login popup and listening out for responses.

Comment: yes, your right, i did copy the the code from facebook example, and i have deleted && response.post_id, and now the request is working good,but how can i handle the response (when the receiver clicks the "accept" button)?? as i mentioned i want the receiver by clicking "accept" to create a new user if is not already a user in my app, and also adding the new user to a group that the sender invited him.

Comment: I haven't tried using this feature of the FB API myself but from reading the docs it looks like it's mainly intended for games built based on facebook.com itself: "Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps. Accepting a request from a game will direct the person to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request." When a recipient clicks accept for a request you have sent where do they get directed to?

Comment: yeah i have read it,but it dosent make sense,why only for games? and if i press "accpet" from facebook , it is direct me to my app. (localhost). i guess i need to find some other way around this.